# BottomTabNavigator change icon color dynamically in a functional component with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i've been trying to change the color of the icon when a user clicks in another icon of the bottomtabnavigator i've managed to change the background color and label color but not the icon, any help is welcome.

```
Mainflow:createBottomTabNavigator({

    Home:{
       screen:Main,
       navigationOptions:{  
        tabBarLabel:'Blood',  
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="drink" color="white" size={30}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
        )  
      } 

    },

    Chart:{
    screen:History,

       navigationOptions:{  
        tabBarLabel:'History',  
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="chart-bar" color="white" size={30}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
        )  
      },
      tabBarOptions:{
        activeTintColor:"blue"
      } 

    },



    Options:{
      screen:History,
         navigationOptions:{ 

          tabBarLabel:'Options',  
          tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
              <MaterialIcons name="person" color="white" size={30}></MaterialIcons>
          )  
        } 

      }

    },
```

That is my navigator, im changing the label color with navigationOptions inside the functional component like so

```
History.navigationOptions = function ({ navigation }) { 
return {

    tabBarIcon:<MaterialCommunityIcons name="food-fork-drink" color="black" size={30}></MaterialCommunityIcons>,


    tabBarOptions: {
      tabBarIcon:<MaterialCommunityIcons name="food-fork-drink" color="black" size={30}></MaterialCommunityIcons>,

      tabBarLabel:"cambio",
       showIcon:true,
      activeTintColor: '#0082FB',
      adaptive:true,
      labelPosition:"below-icon",
      iconStyle:{
        color:"blue"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        color:"blue",
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight:"bold",

      },
      style: {
        color:"blue",
        backgroundColor: '#0082FB',      
        height:height*0.10,
        position:"absolute",        
        borderTopColor: "transparent"
      },


  },


  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the screenshot of what you have done so far

Comment: Hello can you be more specific? what i've tried is to change it from inside the functional component using navigationOptions as show above, also i've tried to change it from another screen but i don't have access to the tabBarIcon prop of the navigator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change to icon color, you can archive via `tintColor` props.

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home:{
       screen:Main,
       navigationOptions:{  
        tabBarLabel:'Blood',  
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="drink" color={tintColor} size={30}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
        )
      }
    },

    Chart:{
      screen:History,
      navigationOptions:{  
        tabBarLabel:'History',  
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="chart-bar" color={tintColor} size={30}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
        )  
      }
    },
    Options:{
      screen:History,
       navigationOptions:{ 
        tabBarLabel:'Options',  
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(  
            <MaterialIcons name="person" color="white" size={30}></MaterialIcons>
        )  
      } 
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'white', // --> active icon color
      inactiveTintColor: 'black', // --> inactive icon color
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add tabBarActiveTintColor: 'your color' to screenOptions of your Navigator like this

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={({route}) => ({
   tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000',
   ...otherOptions
  })}>
    ...your screens
</Tab.Navigator>
```